# how to insert data into table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i created this table

```
create table courses (
cid int primary key not null,
cname varchar(25) )
```

and when i tried to insert any thing like that

```
insert into courses values (1,name)
```

i have this error

```
insert into courses values (1,`ahmed`)
```

> Error Code: 1054. Champ 'ahmed' inconnu dans field list   0.000 sec

when i try to add only cid it's ok , i removed the table and created it twice and the same problem

what is the wrong thing here?

Comment: insert into courses values (1,'ahmed') : try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put **Single quote (')** for string values

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO courses (cid, cname)
VALUES (1, 'ahmed');
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to delimit your `varchar` values with single quotes (`'`).

Try the following instead:

```
insert into courses values (1,'ahmed');
```

Numerics can be passed without the single quotes, however any `char` or `varchar` derived types need the single quotes. Look up `datatypes` for `SQL` for further information.

Comment: Try changing your statement, you are using the `back-tick` ` instead of a single quote `'`, copy the statement directly from my answer and try executing it. I believe mysql uses `back-tick` to delimit objects ( tables, columns, etc...) single quotes are used to delimit values.